# MariaDB Error 1075 no permite cambio de MyISAM a InnoDB

Tags: mariadb, innodb, autoincremento, myisam

Tengo una tabla creada con:

CREATE TABLE `biblioteca_adjuntos` (
`id_biblioteca` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`id_adjunto` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`adjunto` longblob DEFAULT NULL,
`nombre` varchar(160) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`tipo` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`tamanio` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id_biblioteca`,`id_adjunto`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_spanish_ci

Cuando trato de migrarla de MyISAM a InnoDB me arroja el error:
ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Pero según yo lo entiendo, la tabla SI cumple con que el campo con autoincremento es UNICO y es PK en la tabla, sólo que la PK está compuesta por 2 campos..

Alguien ha tenido un problema similar o se le ocurre una solución para poder migrar a InnoDB?.

Answer (score 0):

La posibilidad de especificar `AUTO_INCREMENT` en una columna secundaria en un índice de varias columnas **es una característica propia de `MyISAM`**, eso no lo puedes hacer en `InnoDB`.

El [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) es claro al respecto:

> ##### MyISAM Notes
>
> For `MyISAM` tables, you can specify `AUTO_INCREMENT` on a secondary
> column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value
> for the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column is calculated as
> `MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix`. This is
> useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.
>
> ##### InnoDB Notes
>
> For information about `AUTO_INCREMENT` usage specific to `InnoDB`, see
> [Section 17.6.1.6, “AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html).

---

> ##### Notas sobre MyISAM
>
> Para las tablas `MyISAM`, puede especificar `AUTO_INCREMENT` en una
> columna secundaria en un índice de varias columnas. En este caso, el
> valor generado para la columna `AUTO_INCREMENT` se calcula como
> `MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix`. Esto es
> útil cuando desea colocar datos en grupos ordenados.
>
> ##### Notas sobre InnoDB
>
> Para obtener información sobre el uso de `AUTO_INCREMENT` específico
> de `InnoDB`, consulte la [Sección 17.6.1.6, “Manejo de AUTO_INCREMENT
> en InnoDB”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html).

Desde el `CREATE TABLE` la única posibilidad que tienes aquí de emular lo que hay en tu código de MyISAM es definir `id_biblioteca` como `UNIQUE`. He aquí un ejemplo:

```
create table `biblioteca_adjuntos`( 
  `id_adjunto` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `id_biblioteca` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
  `adjunto` longblob DEFAULT NULL, 
  `nombre` varchar(160) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  `tipo` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  `tamanio` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_adjunto`),
  UNIQUE (`id_biblioteca`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_spanish_ci;
```

```
INSERT INTO `biblioteca_adjuntos` (`id_adjunto`,`id_biblioteca`)VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO `biblioteca_adjuntos` (`id_adjunto`,`id_biblioteca`)VALUES (2,2);
SELECT `id_adjunto`,`id_biblioteca` FROM `biblioteca_adjuntos`;
```

| id_adjunto | id_biblioteca |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

```
-- Esta dará error
INSERT INTO `biblioteca_adjuntos` (`id_adjunto`,`id_biblioteca`)VALUES (2,2);
```

> ```
> Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MFDB2SBm)

Pero esto no tiene mucho sentido realmente y tampoco queda claro en la pregunta cuál es la intención de este código. Si lo que quieres **realmente** es una especie de `AUTO_INCREMENT` basado en dos columnas, podrías hacerlo mediante un `TRIGGER`, como se explica en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18120156/5587982).